# Solving $(1+x^{2})y''+y=0$ using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I've been trying to work on a solution for this equation

$$
(1+x{ ²})y''+y=0
$$

using power series around $x_{0}=0$. So far, I have reached the following recursion relation:

$$
a_{n+2}=\frac{-a_{n}(n^{2}-n+1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}
$$

but I have been struggling to find a generic form for the coefficients. $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ are free since there are no initial conditions to be applied. Any thoughts on how to write  this solution?

---

Edit: coefficients need to be real.

Comment: Assuming your work is correct, that’s probably as good as it gets.

Comment: $a_1, a_0$ are free as you noticed so they can be any numbers.

Comment: @Aruralreader that's the thing, I'd hope for some kind of simple(ish) way to write $a_{2n}$, $a_{2n+1}$ that depends only on $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$. I know it's possible because Symbolab gives it to me, but I'm cheap and I won't pay for it to show the step-by-step development

Comment: If you just want an exercise of this kind there is $(1+x^2)y''-2y=0$ which is much more instructive and can be solve with power series or directly.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze thanks, but I should have pointed out that the coefficients need to be Real

Comment: Your recursion has the solution $a(n)= \frac{i^n 2^{n-2} \left(c_2 (-1)^n+c_1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(2 n-i \sqrt{3}-1\right)\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(2 n+i \sqrt{3}-1\right)\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\right) \Gamma (n+1)}$. Here $\Gamma()$ is the Gamma function and $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants to be adapted to the initial conditions.

Comment: Using the last comment your ODE has the solution in terms of the hypergeometric function $\, _2F_1$: $y(x) = c_1 \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1}}{2},\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{2/3};\frac{1}{2};-x^2\right)+c_2 x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1}}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{2/3};\frac{3}{2};-x^2\right)$

Comment: @ Francisco No, the coefficients need not be real. They depend on the two constants $c_1$ which can be complex.

Answer (score 1):

With $$a_n=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot 2^{n}\cdot \Gamma \! \left(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\cdot \Gamma \! \left(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\cdot \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{a_{0}}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\cdot \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)} & n::\mathit{even} 
\\
 \frac{-\frac{i}{2}\cdot a_{1}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\cdot \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)} & n::\mathit{odd} 
\end{array}\right.\right)}{\Gamma \! \left(n+1\right)}$$

for $n > 1$ we get

$$y(x)=a_0+a_1 x-\frac{1}{2}a_0 x^2-\frac{1}{6}a_1 x^3+\frac{1}{8}a_0 x^4+\frac{7}{120}a_1 x^5+...$$